# PIC16F886 Low Voltage Mode

Tags: arduino, pic, programmer, isp, icsp

I want to program a pic microcontroller, specifically, the PIC16F886.
I am not experienced with programming PIC microcontrollers, however, after searching, I was able to find that you can program this with an Arduino, as ArduinoISP.

However, in order to do that, the PIC microcontroller has to support Low Voltage programming (LVP).

I saw this reference that says how to check if the microcontroller you want, can support LVP: https://microchipsupport.force.com/s/article/How-to-check-if-a-device-has-Low-Voltage-programming-LVP

It says to:

1. Check "MEMORY PROGRAMMING SPECIFICATIONS" the levels of the MCLR/VPP and VDD pins.You can verify if they are the same or different and also ​refer to the AC/DC characteristics.
2. Another thing to look in is the Programming Specification document of the device at the "Entering ICSP Mode" section.

I found the datasheet for this pic microcontroller located here: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/41291d.pdf

However, after searching the document for the strings "MEMORY PROGRAMMING SPECIFICATIONS" or "Entering ICSP Mode", I found nothing.

After searching for the strings "MCLR/VPP" I had 16 results and the string "LVP" gives me 2 results.
However, I was unable to understand if this device supports Low Voltage Programming mode.

Does the PIC16F886 support LVP mode?

Comment: Also  consider using a PICKit programmer, they make things very simple in my experience, at least in a Windows development environment (which I use).

Comment: @IanBland I wan interested in the Arduino as a programmer, because I didn't want to commit to buying a PICKit, as I will not work with these for a long time. But thanks for the reccomendation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Microchip's "PIC16F88X Memory Programming Specification" [[link](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41287D.pdf)] for how to do it.

> The PIC16F88X can be programmed using the high-
> voltage In-Circuit Serial Programming (ICSP)
> method or the low-voltage ICSP method. Both of these
> can be done with the device in the user’s system.

Note this is enabled in its configuration (which it is at the factory), and requires that pin `RB3` is used as `PGM`.  See configuration bit `LVP` in Configuration Word 1.

Comment: Thank! This means that the PIC16F886 can support Low Voltage Mode? Because if yes, this means I can program it with an Arduino.

Comment: Yes indeed.  Here's a [tutorial](https://diyodemag.com/projects/arduino_pic_programmer) but for a different PIC.  It will be very similar, possibly identical.

Comment: Thank you very much!